# multiple udp sockets vs one centralized

Tags: java, c#, sockets, udp, ipc

I have an application, or rather two (in c# and java) that are using udp for IPC. They are streaming large numbers of small packets between each other (about 24 packets of average size around 15 bytes at 50 hz.)

My question is in regards to efficiency. Would it help efficiency significantly combine the data transmission into one thread and have each application access it's own data through that object, or would it be viable to simply have each object that needs to stream data take its own port and run on its own thread.

For the sake of simplicity I would prefer to implement the second one, but if it causes significant slowdowns there won't be any architectural issues combining them all.

Comment: I once wrote a streaming media server (RTSP/RTP) in C#, where each outgoing port had it's own dedicated thread. Performance was dramatically improved by making each port transmit on a single thread. Sending data via UDP is very fast, so you can support writing to a huge number of ports on a single thread. However, you will ultimately need to try them both and measure to really get an answer. See Eric Lippert's famous [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) ;-)

Comment: Seems to make sense. How many ports did you have open at once on average?

Comment: I'll actually simply write both then. I should get back to this thread with an answer in a few days once it's completed both ways. Woo for branching!

Comment: I noticed performance becoming unacceptable with 150 clients (which in RTP is 300 poets, but 150 of those ports only send every 5 seconds (the other 150 every 20ms))